# How can I improve it with regularization?

Tags: boosting, gradient-descent

Why too large value of lambda causes my data to underfit in gradient descent boosting trees?

How can I improve it with regularization?

Answer (score 0):

What about reducing (removing) regularization ?

Regularization prevents the models (trees (?)) from being fully grown (prunning nodes (?)). If you had an infinite regularization no model would be grown !